# No app, AppBundle folders

Tags: symfony

I'm new in learning symfony. Why everytime when I create a new project in symfony it is created without "app" folder in it and there is not AppBundle folder in "src"?

Comment: @nozimasilmova, can you show your code when you first time create?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want `app` folder, `AppBundle` in `src` etc use not symfony skeleton to create new project, create your project with

`composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition your_project_name`

Comment: You saved a head-ache, I just cant believe symfony does not make it clear!

Answer (score 0):

It’s totally normal, it’s the new Symfony philosophy,
http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-directory-structure.html
But you can create it if you miss them ;-)

Comment: but for the beginning I wanted to have these folders automatically created in my new project. What should I do for this or should I install something?

Comment: @NozimaSalimova  For S4 you will get the new structure.  If you really insist on the old structure the follow the 3.4 section of the documentation.  You can set the version in the upper right corner of the docs.  Just remember to always look at the 3.4 version of the docs otherwise you will get even more confused.